# Set navigation always at top

Tags: html, css

i have a header which height is 150px i have 2 elements inside. One is an image and below it is the navigation. how to i get my navigion to always display at top when im scrolling?

It wont work with position fixed because the top margin for the navigation is about 90px. if i use postion fixed the navigation will always have a margin-top:90px; and i want it to have the margin 0.

here is some of the current code:

```
  header
    {
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        height:150px;
        padding:0 20px;
    }

nav
{
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:40px;
    width:700px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px #090807;
    background-color:Orange;
}

nav ul 
{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Sorry bit confused. You want it always ontop, but you give it a margin-top:90px; because? You say you want it always 0, so why dont you remove the 90px ?

Answer (score 0):

It **will** work with position fixed.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: -90px;
}
```

Or you could force the `margin-top: 0` with `!important`:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```